# Hi-DPI mode on Mac using Tkinter on Python

Tags: python, macos, tkinter, scale

I am writing an application that shows info and must run on linux, windows, and mac devices.
In windows and linux devices works well in normal and HiDPI screens with the 
`root.tk.call('tk','scaling',2.0)` but in Mac OS, the command doesn't work.

Is any difference between linux and mac, I thought that mac runs X11 for the windows too and the command should run, but it doesn't.

And, how do I double the resolution of the images to display well on HiDPI screens without change the scale factor, because changing the scale only changes the font.

Thanks.

Comment: _"I thought that mac runs X11 for the windows too "_ - unless you've explicitly built tkinter to use X11, it doesn't.

Comment: So, by default, OSX doesn't run X11. Knowing that, what command should I use to adapt the interface DPI in OSX?